# Bootstrap DateTimePicker (eonasdan) format date as DD/MMM/YYYY

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, momentjs, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I'm having quite of a problem regarding this bootstrap plugin below.

http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

I have an initial value of `"15/05/1992"` which has an initial format of `"DD/MM/YYYY"`, now using this plugin which also use moments as its base. I want to format it like this "15/May/1992" but Every time I format it using `'DD/MMM/YYYY'` it is not working as it should be. It is showing as `"15/Jan/1992"` which is wrong because the month should be `May`.

I also test another date like `"19/02/2198"` applying the same steps above and it is showing as `"19/Jan/2002"` which very very wrong. I don't know if it has something to do with `moments.js` but I'm really stuck on this right now.

Any help will be much appreciated! Thanks!

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
         <h6>datetimepicker1</h6>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="15/05/1992" />   <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script.

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({format : "DD/MMM/YYYY"});
```

See Sample
http://jsfiddle.net/byx1couq/2/

Comment: Show some codes you have written

Comment: just see the jsfiddle, its not working on it either.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow.  It's fine to link to a fiddle, but you also need to show a minimal example here.  The question should stand alone, and the fiddle can be used to supplement.

Comment: You cannot set value attribute directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't try to set the `value` attribute directly.  Doing so will always use the locale format of the browser, so you can't really control it.

Instead, use the `date` function from the date picker control ([see docs here](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#date)).  Since it can accept a `moment` object, that is your best bet for fine control over the input format.

```
$('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").date(moment("15/05/1992","DD/MM/YYYY"));
```

[Updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/byx1couq/3/).

Comment: Hi @Matt, It is working fine now! I like the fact that even though i supplied an empty date string the datetimepicker is still working as it should be.  Thank you very much! Good stuff man! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize your picker value using [defaultDate](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#defaultdate) option:

```js
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
 format : "DD/MMM/YYYY",
    defaultDate: moment("15/05/1992","DD/MM/YYYY")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/d004434a5ff76e7b97c8b07c01f34ca69e635d97/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/d004434a5ff76e7b97c8b07c01f34ca69e635d97/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h6>datetimepicker1</h6>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Avoid setting input value in the HTML or using jQuery `val()`. If you need to set a value,  do it using [date](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#date) function as suggested in other answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It is working now as it should be but when I tried initializing the DateTimePicker with an empty date string using your code above, it is throwing an error which of course will happen but this will cause the datetimepicker to stop working. using @Matt answer suits me best since even though I supplied an empty string the datetimepicker will still successfully initialize. Thanks again!